# Securely Streaming Videos in Flutter with MongoDB based on authorization

Tags: mongodb, flutter, mongodb-security

I am working on a video streaming platform where I only want to allow premium users to access certain videos. I can store videos in CDN and save their URLs in MongoDB but that would give access to the video to everyone having that link. Is there any way to implement this in flutter based on authorization?

Comment: does your cdn support user pass authentication for each directory and provide this by API ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi I am currently in the planning phase. I can use any CDN which fits best in my use case.